# Angular.js Chosen integration

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jquery-chosen

my select inside my angular view where i want to add chosen functionality:

```
<select ng-options="value for value in deutscheBankEvent.dates" ng-init="" ng-model="chosenA" class="chzn-select">
 <option style="display:none" value="">Wählen Sie ein Datum</option>
 </select><br/>
```

my controller: when i inject here the .chosen function, it clears the options.

```
function Ctrl($scope,$http) {

  $scope.text = '';
  $scope.user = {name: '', last: '', location: ''};
  $scope.value = 0;
  $scope.sendForm = function (){
       $http.post('/Submit/To/Url', $scope.data).success(function(data) {
           alert('done!');
       });
    };
}
```

my footer:

```
<g:javascript>
 $(".chzn-select").chosen(); $(".chzn-select-deselect").chosen({allow_single_deselect:true});
            jQuery(".adressen1_chzn-select").chosen();jQuery(".adressen0_chzn-select").chosen();
        });
</g:javascript>
```

i have no idea, how to get the chosen working. inside controller it clears options and does not apply, the rest does not make any difference. any ideas appreciated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should maybe try http://angular-ui.github.com/

It's a suite of angular directives. Among them you'll find 'select2' directive which serves as a proxy to *Chosen* plugin (*Select2* plugin to be precise).

Comment: Select2 is not the same as chosen.

Comment: Second solution is easier, I should have scrolled down sooner!

Answer (score 10):

Your solution won't work because jQuery code would fire before the element is actually created in the DOM. You should solve this problem using a directive on the form element.

Element needs to be created dynamically and therefore you are in fact operating on the DOM element - perfect fit for Angular's directives. No use of jQuery is necessary and try to avoid it while working with Angular. Note that jQuery is still required due to *Chosen* dependencies.

I solve the problem using this set:

1. angular-chosen directive https://github.com/localytics/angular-chosen
2. [OPTIONAL] Bootstrap3 styling https://github.com/alxlit/bootstrap-chosen

I suggest you to try writing the directive yourself. It's a nice practice. You can try with this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ozyXwLzFYs

Good luck!

Comment: This is THE solution. It works on the very same SELECT. On the other hand, AngularUI UI-Select is very hard to implement, it is a whole different semantic.