# Integrate Chosen into AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm trying to integrate Chosen (jquery plugin) with AngularJS, but I can't get it to populate any options in the select.

I started following this tutorial:

http://onehungrymind.com/angularjs-chosen-plugin-awesome/

and created this simple example (with help from '[Chosen Angular directive doesn't get updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18262442/chosen-angular-directive-doesnt-get-updated)'):

http://plnkr.co/edit/BzLAdotxKVI15t5phNAA?p=preview

```
module.directive('chosen', function(){

var directive = {};

    directive.restrict = 'A';


    directive.link = function(scope, element, attrs) {

        var list = attrs['chosen'];

        scope.$watch(list, function () {
            element.trigger('chosen:updated');
        });

        scope.$watch(attrs['ngModel'], function() {
            element.trigger('chosen:updated');
        });

        element.chosen();
    };

    return directive;
});
```

which doesn't error but doesn't add anything to the list. If I remove the "chosen" attribute from the select, it works as expected so I know it's not a problem with the bindings.

I then tried using the angular-chosen wrapper:

https://github.com/localytics/angular-chosen
(referenced in this question - [Angular.js Chosen integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15069697/angular-js-chosen-integration) and (probably) [AngularJS Chosen not working/updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25295269/angularjs-chosen-not-working-updating))

and created this:
http://plnkr.co/edit/NmQiDgU1xOK8l9MtTcjS?p=preview

Which has the same problem.

**UPDATE**
In response to **Jose M** - I looked at ui-select but it requires a lot of (not-intuitive) markup instead of just an attribute, so I ruled it out.

**UPDATE**
In response to **jd17* - * Working plunkr from the answer below:
http://plnkr.co/edit/2v3BWVL0xFgQVce0MPXR?p=preview

Comment: That looks a lot like the Select2 one, and there is already an angularjs implementation in angular-ui, check out ui-select: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select

Comment: I looked at ui-select but decided it wasn't really what I wanted - I've updated the question with reason why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your app.js, why did you redefine "chosen" directive since you are using the Angular Chosen plugin?
 I modified your app.js in your second plnkr as follow and things works well.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',['localytics.directives']); // inject the chosen

app.controller('TestController', ['$scope','$http',
function TestController($scope,$http){

  $scope.url = 'testValues.json';
  $scope.wordList = [];
  $scope.selectedWord = {};

  $scope.loadWords = function(){
    $http.get($scope.url).then(function(result){
      $scope.wordList = result.data;
    });
  };

  $scope.loadWords();
}
]);
```

Comment: I copied the original plunkr - so I forgot to delete my "chosen" directive. Works great now - thanks! (I've updated the second plunkr at the bottom of the question)